# Opposite of sadism?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Not masochism..!
Sadism is the derivation of pleasure from others' suffering.
Is there a word for the derivation of pleasure from others' happiness?

Comment: Like [altruism](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/altruism)?

Comment: empathy and sympathy help one share the feelings of others ... and with sympathy you would "feel their pain"... however you're looking not so much for an opposite of "pleasure from suffering" but a term for "pleasure from their success" (which neither empathy nor sympathy convey)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!  The word is ***compersion***.  It is common among those interested in or practicing polyamory and it is becoming more common in general use as well.  Parents are well acquainted with the concept -- I had tears of joy streaming down my face watching my daughter perform at Disneyland recently.

> ***[Compersion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compersion)***
>
> Noun
>
> **compersion** (uncountable)
>
> 1. The feeling of joy one has experiencing another's joy, such as in witnessing a toddler's joy and feeling joy in response.
> 2. The feeling of joy associated with seeing a loved one love another; contrasted with jealousy.
>
> **Antonyms**
>
> jealousy

Here's an [article at Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/gracie-x/compersion-a-polyamorous-principle-that-can-strengthen-any-relationship_b_6803868.html) about the concept and one from [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-polyamorists-next-door/201312/jealousy-and-compersion-multiple-partners-1).

Hope this helps.  (I would get a lot of joy from your happiness at learning this word! 8^)

Comment: Sadly it does not appear in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compersion), [Oxford](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=compersion&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch), [Oxford Living](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?filter=dictionary&query=compersion), [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/spellcheck/english/?q=compersion), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english?q=compersion), or [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=compersion)